# Delegating events by parsing strings in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Recently I have been playing around with some of the more complicated aspects of JavaScript, one of which is design patterns and delegation.

I have created a object containing 2 keys, which I then parse and attach an event onto the body.

My problem is that it seems like the last function is attached for any iteration of the for loop. I am pretty sure this is a copy by reference/scoping(thanks Shmiddty) problem, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there anyway to fix my issue to attach the 2 events on properly without changing too much? (As this is a complex app that I have simplified down to the issue at hand).

On the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TXjjn/2/) please see how the alert message for `.div1` is the same as `.div2`

```
var foo = {
    init: function() {

        var i = 0,
            keys = []
            self = this;

        for (var key in this) {
            keys.push(key);
        }

        for (i; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (keys[i].match(/^on/i)) {
                var delegateFunc = keys[i].split(' | '),
                    event = delegateFunc[2],
                    selector = delegateFunc[1],
                    keyName = keys[i];

                console.log('###');
                console.log( 'selector: ' + selector );
                console.log( 'event: ' + event );
                console.log( 'function: ' + self[keyName] );

                $('body').on(event, selector, function(ev) {
                    self[keyName](ev, ev.target);
                });
            }
        }

    },

    'on | .div1 | click': function(ev, el) {
        alert('you clicked 1');
    },

    'on | .div2 | click': function(ev, el) {
        alert('you clicked 2');
    }
}

$(function() { foo.init(); });​
```

Any more info needed? Leave me a comment. Cheers

Comment: @Shmiddty Could you please explain what you mean rather than put a joking comment on my question?

Comment: I mean that this question is asked roughly a dozen times a day.

Comment: Could you point to a question that could fix my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            $('body').on(event, selector, function(ev) {
                self[keyName](ev, ev.target);
            });
```

replace this with the following code:

```
            (function(keyName) {
                $('body').on(event, selector, function(ev) {
                    self[keyName](ev, ev.target);
                });
            })(keyName);
```

The reason for this is that JavaScript doesn't have a block scope. So your `var keyName` is the same variable in each loop and the closure of your callback function binds the variable, not the value it has at that moment. So as soon as the loop finished the variable will be whatever its last value was in *all* your callback functions.

By adding the immediately-executed function which takes `keyName` as an argument you create a *new* variable (the function argument) and thus avoid the issue.

Comment: Thank you @ThiefMaster your answer was the quickest/easiest to understand answer of them all. I'll mark as accepted once I can

Comment: "self-executing" is a misleading term. "Immediately Invoked" is more accurate, since the function isn't self-aware. Or has skynet become self-aware?

Answer (score 1):

**Classic closure issue..**

Put your for loop in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
for (i; i < keys.length; i++) {
            (function(lockedIndex) {
                if (keys[lockedIndex].match(/^on/i)) {
                    var delegateFunc = keys[lockedIndex].split(' | '),
                        event = delegateFunc[2],
                        selector = delegateFunc[1],
                        keyName = keys[lockedIndex];

                    console.log('###');
                    console.log('selector: ' + selector);
                    console.log('event: ' + event);
                    console.log('function: ' + self[keyName]);

                    $('body').on(event, selector, function(ev) {
                        self[keyName](ev, ev.target);
                    });
                }
            })(i)
        }
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXjjn/3/)**

Comment: He doesn't even need to lock the index in his case. `keyName` was the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the link for me to read through, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

`keyName` is stale by the time your event handler is triggered, you need to wrap it in a new scope:

```
(function(key) {
    $('body').on(event, selector, function(ev) {
        self[key](ev, ev.target);
    });
})(keyName);
```